# How to delete all files in a directory, keeping sub-directories intact

Tags: python, file, directory

How can I delete all files in a directory but keep all its sub-directories intact?

Starting with a directory like:

```
root
|-- somedir
|   |-- file1.txt
|   |-- file2.txt
|   |-- deleteme.ext
|   |-- subfolder1
|   |   |-- important_file.dbf
|   |-- subfolder2
|   |   |-- business_critical.xls
```

I want to end up with

```
root
|-- somedir
|   |-- subfolder1
|   |   |-- important_file.dbf
|   |-- subfolder2
|   |   |-- business_critical.xls
```

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Filtering out sub-directories.

Comment: How about using [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile):

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,f))]
for fname in files:
    fpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
    os.remove(fpath)
```

Comment: List comprehension sure is elegant, but I'm not sure I fully get the `f for f`.

Comment: @Agostino see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It just does not recognize any file as such. I think it's because `os.path.isfile` only gets the filename, and not the whole path.

Comment: @Agostino You're right. I fixed it. I wonder why no one (including myself) noticed it.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that `path+f` will work in 100% of cases?

Comment: Nope, it won't. I messed it up again. I think I actually fixed it, though, now.

Comment: That tends to happen when the number statements per line increases :P